# How to create a new Jagged Array given other arrays? Is there a method to delete an element from an array?

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

```
public class Yearly { 

    public void getYearlyData() throws FileNotFoundException  {

        String[] state = StatesList.getValues();
        int numberOfStates = state.length;
```

I have an array: `String[] state`, which contains the names of the states specified by the user.

It may look like this: `String[] state = {"Illinois", "Kansas", "Wyoming"};`

The following is the two dimentional jagged array. The first subelement of each element is the  name of the state, then there are names of the Newspapers in that state.

```
String statePapersInitial[][] = {
                { "Alabama", "BGNB"},
                { "Alaska", "ADNB", "ALKP"},
                { "Arizona", "ADSB" },
                ..................//Total = 51.................
                { "Wyoming","WTEB", "WYOM", "WMPP"};
```

The goal is to create a new jagged array that would include only those elements of `statePapersInitial` array that contain the names of the states that have beenchoosen by the user in the `state` array.

I called the new array `statePapers`

I have tried the following:

```
String[][] statePapers = null;  
int x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < state.length; x++)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < statePapersInitial.length; i++)
    {   
        if (state[x].equals(statePapersInitial[i][0]))
        {
            int j = 1;
            for (j = 1; j < statePapersInitial[i].length; j++)
                statePapers[x][j-1] = statePapersInitial[i][j];
            System.out.println(statePapers[x][j-1]);
        }
        else;
    }
}
```

However, it does not work, it throws an Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Yearly.getYearlyData(Yearly.java:95)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: statePapers is null because you never created it.

Comment: This seems like a perfect application for a `Map<String, List<String>`

Comment: Forget about arrays.  You should use a map.  Regarding your Exception message: you need to initialize arrays before you use them.  Your code sets _statePapers_ to null and never initializes it.

Comment: Or a Multimap! http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html

Comment: That's a good idea, I' check out the Multimap thing. You are right, I assigned null to statePapers... Anyways, I think that Multimap would do a better job. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just arrays:

```
public class q14968543 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String statePapersInitial[][] = {
      { "Alabama", "BGNB" },
      { "Alaska",  "ADNB", "ALKP" },
      { "Arizona", "ADSB" },
      { "Wyoming", "WTEB", "WYOM", "WMPP" }
    };

    for(String[] papers : selectOnly(statePapersInitial, "Alabama", "Wyoming")) {
      for(String paper : papers) {
        System.out.print(paper+ " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  private static String[][] selectOnly(String[][] statePapers, String ... states) {
    String[][] selected = new String[states.length][0];
    int index = 0;
    for(String state : states) {
      for(String[] papers : statePapers) {
        if(state.equals(papers[0])) {
          selected[index++] = papers;
        }
      }
    }
    return selected;
  }
}
```

the output is:

```
Alabama BGNB 
Wyoming WTEB WYOM WMPP
```

Now an approach that uses `Map`s might look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class q14968543 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> statePapers = new HashMap<>();
    statePapers.put("Alabama", Arrays.asList((new String[] {"BGNB"})));
    statePapers.put("Alaska",  Arrays.asList((new String[] {"ADNB", "ALKP"})));
    statePapers.put("Arizona", Arrays.asList((new String[] {"ADSB"})));
    statePapers.put("Wyoming", Arrays.asList((new String[] {"WTEB", "WYOM", "WMPP"})));

    for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> state : selectOnly(statePapers, "Alabama", "NOT A STATE", "Wyoming").entrySet()) {
      System.out.print(state.getKey()+"=");
      for(String paper : state.getValue()) {
        System.out.print(paper+ " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  private static Map<String, List<String>> selectOnly(Map<String, List<String>> statePapers, String ... states) {
    Map<String, List<String>> selected = new HashMap<>();
    for(String state : states) {
      if(statePapers.containsKey(state)) {
        selected.put(state, statePapers.get(state));
      }
    }
    return selected;
  }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Wyoming=WTEB WYOM WMPP 
Alabama=BGNB
```

Here you can see that it is ignoring the `"NOT A STATE"` that was passed, and it is using the State name as a key as opposed to the first element in an array.

Comment: One problem with this code is that there is no error checking if the state you want to select exists in the original array (the side effect would be a return array that is larger than the data being returned), but it should get you started.  However a proper data-type would be cleaner

Comment: Hi @Jason Sperske. May I ask you one more question. How can I (instead of printing it to console), assign these values to a new String such that: String[][] myNewString = {{"Alabama", "BGNB"}, {"Wyoming", "WTEB", "WYOM", "WMPP"}};

Comment: This should work: `String[][] myNewString = selectOnly(statePapersInitial, "Alabama", "Wyoming");` this was in my original answer, but I though I was being clever by just dumping into that for loop :P

Comment: @Buras I added the Map approach to my answer